# Making a custom x in shopping cart

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am trying a custom red x in my table as shown below. 
[image: mockup].

In my html I have

```
<td>$4.99</td>
<td><%= link_to 'Remove', purchase_path(a), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td
```

I want to replace the word 'Remove' with the x. I am having trouble how to go about this while keeping the link_to in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<%= link_to  purchase_path(a), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} do %>
  YOUR ICON HERE
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can use the html &times; for x instead of an icon or 'X'. It's better for accessibility